# Как остановить аудиозапись playlistManager, которая находится в другом классе?

Tags: java, android

Включается проигрывание playlistManager в четвертом классе, далее возвращаюсь ко второму классу, аудиозапись также играет, необходимо при нажатии на кнопку во втором классе отключить (`stop();`) проигрывание аудиозаписи.

Сама процедура ясна, как день, (по крайней мере мне так кажется). Делаю импорт четвертого класса во второй класс, далее через `ЧетвертыйКласс.stop();` вызываю метод остановки аудиозаписи из четвертого класса, НО вылазит ошибка о `"Non-static method 'stop()' cannot be referenced from a static context"`

Казалось бы понятно, но как её можно обойти без изменения static?

ПС: после выхода из четвертого класса, аудиозапись играет фоново